# Edit pdf template based on user input

Tags: node.js, express, multer, jspdf, pdfkit

I have a pdf template with information my client (client name, city, photos).

I'm trying to make a form that let the user (me) input my new client info and then generate a pdf (based on my template with this new client info).

I was working with nodejs, express, multer.

index.html form looks like this:

```html
<form id="form" action="/admin/add" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<!-- (...) -->
<div class="spot">
        <label for="photo_1_0">Photo 1:</label>
        <input type="file" id="photo_1_0" name="photo_1_0" required />
        <label for="photo_2_0">Photo 2:</label>
        <input type="file" id="photo_2_0" name="photo_2_0" required />
        <label for="address_0">Address:</label>
        <input type="text" id="address_0" name="address_0" required />
</div>
```

And the client index.js:

```
form.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const client = document.getElementById("client").value;
    const city = document.getElementById("city").value;
    const spotsArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < spotIndex; i++) {
        const photo1 = document.getElementById(`photo_1_${i}`).value;
        const photo2 = document.getElementById(`photo_2_${i}`).value;
        const address = document.getElementById(`address_${i}`).value;
        spotsArray.push({ photo_1: photo1, photo_2: photo2, address });
    }
// for loop above is because user is able to click a button and add another spot (photo_1_1, photo_2_1, address_1)
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("client", client);
    formData.append("city", city);
    spotsArray.forEach((spot, index) => {
        formData.append(`spots[${index}][photo_1]`, spot.photo_1);
        formData.append(`spots[${index}][photo_2]`, spot.photo_2);
        formData.append(`spots[${index}][address]`, spot.address);
    });
    console.log(formData ); // everything looks good here
        fetch("http://localhost:3334/admin/add", {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData,
    });
});
```

Server side:

```js
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, "uploads/");
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.originalname);
    },
});
const upload = multer({ storage });

app.post("/admin/add", upload.any(), (req, res) => { 
    console.log(req.files);
    console.log(req.body);
});
// "uploads/" dir is created and stores all images
```

at this point req.body looks like this:

```js
{
  client: 'my_client_test',
  city: 'my_city_test',
  spots: [
    {
      photo_1: 'C:\\fakepath\\photo_1_test.jpeg',
      photo_2: 'C:\\fakepath\\photo_2_test.jpeg',
      address: 'my_address_test'
    }
  ]
}
```

Is it better if I write my pdf template with html/css, use something like ejs to render req.body values into it and then use jsPDF or pdfkit to print (saving it as a pdf)?
Actually, is there a better way to achieve that? I just need the user to fill the form and on submit generate (download the pdf)

Thanks!